# HP proliant SE316M1 G6 drivers for windows server 2008 R2

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, drivers

I have a HP proliant SE316M1 G6 and we have just installed windows server 2008 R2

the machine didn't come with any drivers and i can't seem to download any 
windows server seems to have found most of the drivers but i have two what are not installed

Base System Device
and
IPMI Interface

can any one help me to trace the drivers that work

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a DL160 Gen6 with dual PSUs so try the usual [SPP](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From [HP and Google](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-NetServers/SE316M1-drivers/ta-p/5366607):

> Question: Do you have any idea where can I download drivers for HP
>   proliant SE316M1 server. As I read HP smartstart don't support this
>   product. Maybe it has a new name now but I don't know which server is
>   it. Can you associate it with an other proliant?
>
> Answer: SE316M1 is equal to a DL160 G6 server. Try the drivers which is
>   used for DL160 G6 server.